# How to comparing DateTime datatype to DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, .net

I have a variable from a datatable using the `datetime` datatype. This datatype is the `"scheduledTime"` column. I am trying to compare the datatime variable to the system clock which would return a difference background color on my table. I am not getting any results with my code and I to get some guidance... Also i am not sure how to define the `"scheduledTime"` datetime variable in my condition

Here is the condition:

if `scheduledTime` is `0-15mins` late then background color red..

if `scheduledTime` is `15min-30mins` late then background color yellow..

if `scheduledTime` is `30mins-2hours` late then background color green..

```
//Row Rendering event
public void Row_Rendering()
{
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.New();
    DateTime scheduledTime = "SCHD DTM"   //<--- this is the name of the column from the table

    int i = DateTime.Compare(scheduleTime,currentTime); 
    if (i <= 0.25)
    {
        Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
        ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
    else if (i > 0.25 && i <=0.5)
    {
       Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
       ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    else if (i > 0.5 && i <=2)
    {
       Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
       ForeColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I quess you forgot to add braces to your `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the difference in minutes between two DateTime values, you can subtract the two DateTimes then call TotalMinutes on them:

```
double differenceInMinutes = (currentTime - scheduledTime).TotalMinutes;
```

You can then use `differenceInMinutes` for your computations accordingly:

```
if (differenceInMinutes <= 15) then
Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
ForeColor = Color.White;

else if (differenceInMinutes > 15 & differenceInMinutes <= 30) then
Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
ForeColor = Color.Black;

else if (differenceInMinutes > 30 & differenceInMinutes <= 120)
Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
ForeColor = Color.White;
```

**UPDATED**

Below's a sample on how to get the DateTime value from a DataTable. Assuming that the DataTable is stored in a variable named `myDataTable` and you are currently on the first row (row index of 0):

```
DateTime scheduledTime = myDataTable.Rows[0]["SCHD DTM"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I can understand your method, but do I have to define my column 2(scheduledTime) for this equation?

Comment: scheduledTime has to already be in a DateTime format. Updated my answer on how to do this if the value is from a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to operate with [TimeStan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object like:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = currentTime - scheduleTime;
```

after that you can simply use `timeSpan.TotalMinutes` property or other `Total...` properties.

Comment: I think you mean something like this for example `dateDuration = (TimeSpan)(dateEndTime - dateStartTime);`

Comment: Kieran perhaps you should read the MSDN site and examples here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s85h2eca.aspx I use this type of thing all the time without any issues along with it's other properties .. try it out and perhaps you will rethink your comment thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can compare TimeSpan values directly

```
            DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime scheduledTime = dataReader.GetDateTime(0);

            TimeSpan timeDifference = scheduledTime - currentTime;
            if (timeDifference <= new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)) //less 15m
            {
                Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
                ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else if (timeDifference <= new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)) //15m - 30m
            {
                Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else if (timeDifference <= new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))//30m - 2hr
            {
                Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
                ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
            else // > 2hr
            {
                //:todo: create styles for time difference > 2 hr
            }
```